# Javascript TypeError, Not a function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, typeerror

I have a function, like following:

```
function handler(){
    // ...
}
```

And I called this function in other js file, like below:

```
if(window.handler())
   handler();
```

But I got following error in firebug console:

TypeError: window.handler is not a function

Anyone can help me?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to check if a function exists, do it in this way:

```
if (window.alertHandler)
    alertHandler();
```

`if (window.myFunc())` runs function first and check the return value. but `if (window.myFunc)` doesn't run it just check if `myFunc` exists in window object.

Answer (score 2):

You either declare your function like this:

```
window.handler = function() {
    // function code here 
};

if (window.handler) { // check if the function actually exist
    window.handler(); // call the function
}
```

or you change the if to:

```
if (typeof handler === 'function') {
    handler();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To invoke this function as method of the window object first you must make it a method of the window object.

```
function somefunction(){
   // ...
}

window.handler = somefunction;

//NOW you can reference it like that

window.handler();
```

As shown in another answer you can also assign an anonymous function directly.